# How to use recursion to reverse text?

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.util.*;
public class RecursionProject {
  public static void main(String[]args) {
    getLine(); 
    useRecursion();
  }
  public static void getLine() {

    System.out.println("This program uses recursion.") ;
    System.out.println("Would you like to see how it works?") ;
    System.out.print("If yes, type yes, else type no -----> ");
    String userResponse = null;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    userResponse = in.next();
    System.out.println(userResponse);
    if (userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
      System.out.println() ;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Thank you for using this program.");
      System.exit(0);
    }

  }
  private static void useRecursion(){
    System.out.println("Type in what you would like to see") ; 
    System.out.println("done recursively. (This program ") ;
    System.out.println("excludes white spaces):") ;
    String s = null ; 
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    s = console.next() ; 
    if (s.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.print(" - ") ;

    }
    else {
      System.out.println("0") ;
    }
  } 
}
```

SO this is my code so far. My assignment is to read input from console, then reverse the phase using Recursion. i.e. if the user typed "animals" it would print out "slamina" to the screen.
I understand that my base case is if the line is empty and my recursive case is if the line has text in it. 
This is a Programming 2 class, using Java on Eclipse 4.2.2

Comment: yeah... we can't do your homework...

Comment: I'm looking for a few pointers. am I in the right direction?

Comment: I don't see any actual logic here - where have your tried to write your recursive code? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I'll be honest. I'm completely lost. I've read my textbook about 3 times about Recursion, but still got no idea what direction to head in.Can i get an explanation on how recursion can be used on a string?

Comment: Hopefully my answer sheds some light on this.  The key thing I think you need to understand is you're solving a problem by repeatedly using the results of a sub-problem, until eventually the sub-problem is trivial to solve.  E.g., the reverse of "Hello" is just the reverse of "ello", with an "H" stuck on the end.  Once you get down to reversing "o", it's trivial.

Comment: It did, thank you for the info. it's helping me understand more

Comment: Glad to help.  Don't forget to upvote any answers you found helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally with recursion you'd have a function that calls itself.  You don't need recursion to reverse a string, but I suppose you could have a function that takes a string, and appends the  first character of the string to the reverse of the rest.

I'll try to explain how this works without giving too much code.

So say you had a function `reverse` that reverses a string.  In it you could say something like:

```
return reverse(myString.substring(1)) + myString[0];
```

When you call it on the string `Hello`, it works like this:

```
reverse("Hello")
-> reverse("ello") + "H"
-> reverse("llo") + "e" + "H" 
-> reverse("lo") + "l" + "e" + "H" 
-> reverse("o") + "l" + "l" + "e" + "H" 
-> "o" + "l" + "l" + "e" + "H"
```

It needs to cut off the recursion when the string is empty.

Comment: if i include my Scanner in the recursive method, when it calls itself again, will it keep pausing for input?

Comment: I would make the recursive method take a string as an argument.  Get the input before calling it.  From your comment, I think you can see why getting input in the recursive method is a problem.

Comment: But before you focus on "How should I write this code" make sure you understand the *idea* of how recursion is being used.  The bit with the repeated reversals of smaller and smaller pieces of the string is the key.  The rest is just details.

Comment: That said, details matter too. :)

Comment: I modified my code  bit, my recursion method now reads a String as an argument. public static String Recursive(String s){
  
  if(s.length()==0) {
   System.out.print("") ;
  }
  else {
   char[] t = s.toCharArray(); 
   s = new String(t) ;
   Recursive(s); 
  }
  System.out.print(s.charAt(0)) ;
  return s ;                                                     Hopefully you understand it, but how can i get closer to my base case? this part is killing me

Comment: If I would you, I would just have the recursive function return the reversed string.  Do the input and output outside of it.  Also, I would give it a name that describes what it does, e.g. `reverse`, not a name that describes *how* it does it, like `recursive`.

Comment: As far as how you make progress, when the recursive function calls itself it should only be passing a piece of the original string, as described in my answer.  I recommend you try to fully understand the answer I posted, and ask questions about whatever you don't understand, rather than posting new attempts and asking why they still don't work.  Once you get the concept, it will be clear why your new attempt still doesn't work.

Comment: in your example the "myString[0]" does this mean to add the index 0 character within an array?

Comment: if it's a String, why would i use this code for an array. could it work equally with "myString.charAt(0)"

Comment: What I mean by that line is:
`reverse(stringStartingFromSecondCharacter) and join to firstCharacter`.  In other words, each call to reverse should move one character from the front of the string to the back, and then apply reverse to the rest of the string.  Do you see how this eventually reverses the whole thing?

Comment: Sure, `myString.charAt(0)`

Comment: Yes i do. Assuming that your line is in an "else" section, and the "if" is myString==0 (being the escape so it won't be infinite), could you write System.out.print(myString) and it print out the new reversed string?

Comment: The way I wrote it, it's not changing myString, it's *returning* the reversed string.  So that's the thing you'd want to print.

Comment: Does your example need a call on itself(method), to reverse the whole String? because the first time it runs itself, it would only do the "reverse("ello") + "H" ". Correct?

Comment: No, calling `reverse("Hello")` should recurse as many times as needed, finally returning `"olleH"`.  Because `reverse("Hello")` calls `reverse("ello")`, which calls `reverse("llo")`, etc. as I describe.

Comment: Oh yes. now that makes more sense than what was in my mind. Thank you so much Tim! This info will definitely help me code in the long run, I hope i can ask you more questions later if i need to?

Comment: Sure.  I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

[`StringBuffer`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) has a built-in `reverse()` method, so just use that.

Here is how you would reverse a `String` such as "Hello World":

```
String source = "Hello World";

    for (String word : source.split(" ")) {
        System.out.print(new StringBuffer(word).reverse().toString());
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```

Output:

```
olleH dlroW
```

---

This is homework, so I'm not going to do it for you.  Basically, to make it recursive you want to create a method that will accept a `String` (or multiple `Strings` with variable arity arguments), then use my code logic to reverse the `String` or `Strings`, and return them. Then you can call upon the method every time you need a `String` to be reversed.

Comment: The assignment is to use recursion.  How is this an example of that?

Comment: So far my thought is to create an if and else conditions. Where if is the base case and else would be my recursive case. BUt i have no idea on how i would start to use recursion

Comment: Exactly, it is an **assignment**, I'm not going to do all the work for him.

Comment: Fair enough, but if he doesn't understand what recursion is, posting a non-recursive answer might increase his confusion.

Comment: I edited my answer to give him a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It will be difficult to offer something that is both useful and not doing your homework for you. I will try but I will not give you working code.

Start with something like this:

```
public static final String reverse ( String s ) {
  if ( s != null && s.length() > 1 ) {
    return (lastChar(s) + allButLastChar(s));
  }
  return s;
}
```

Write `lastChar` and `allButLastChar`, run the code and see what it does. The next step is up to you but it should be obvious.