# How do I use Recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

SO i posted my code. But this question is to just help me understand what recursion is exactly. 
I understand that i need a **base case** and **recursive case**.
My assignment is to read input from the user, and reverse the order of it. "animals" would become "slamina"
Now my **base case**: Would be if the user enters an empty line(which is allowed). 
While my **recursive case**: as long as the input has characters
I am using a string to store the input, and  i might be using the ".charAt[0]" command somewhere in there?

I'm looking for explanation to help me better the code i will need to use for this assignment.
I am using Java on Eclipse

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use recursion to reverse text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398815/how-to-use-recursion-to-reverse-text)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this question is not well suited for SO as it is. Please come up with a *specific* question so that we can answer it in a specific way. As is, there's no way to answer this without writing a tutorial for how recursion works, which is not SO's forte.

Comment: @AdamGent I use recursion in Java all the time. The fact that it's not as concise as it would be in Haskell doesn't mean it can't be done or taught.

Comment: @Armando Garcia - OK, I even did Googling for you.  Please read this: http://danzig.jct.ac.il/java_class/recursion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is code that references itself in its execution thread.
The key to writing recursive code is to identify the repeating pattern and only write that pattern once.

In your case, the pattern is character switching. Consider this psuedo-code:

```
pattern ( string )
    reverse = (all but the first character of the string, reversed)
              + (the first character)
```

The first term could then use the same pattern, namely:

```
pattern(all but the first character of the string)
```

However, to make sure this doesn't run forever, it must be stopped when there are no more characters to switch (i.e. if an irreversible string is encountered):

```
pattern ( string )
    if string length < 2 return string
    else reverse = pattern(all but the first character of the string)
                   + (first character of the string)
    return reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

To use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399074/823393) you must first examine your parameters and decide whether you should use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399074/823393) or not. If your parameters suggest you should use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399074/823393) then you should use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399074/823393) with new parameters, otherwise you should return a result.

You can use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15399074/823393) several times in the same method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can think about this problem:

1. If the string is empty, return an empty string.
2. Otherwise, remove the first character of the string (we'll name it `c`) and call reverse on the leftovers (we'll call it `cs`) then append `c` to the end.

Here's some pseudo code (this won't compile, it's just to give you an idea):

```
reverse(String input)
  if (input.isEmpty())
    return input;
  else {
    String c = getFirstCharacterOfString(input);  //write this on your own
    String cs = getAllCharactersButTheFirst(input); //write this on your own
    return reverse(cs) + c;
  }
```

Comment: ... OR - you could return the last character followed by all the rest.

Comment: Just add a bit of information that might not be obvious for the original poster, reverse method would be the recursion method defined by 1. and 2.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes that would work too

Comment: @Smit: That's what 1) is for

Comment: @tieTYT Sorry I misunderstood. It gets clear with your example. I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I won't try to answer directly since you seem to want to understand how it works, so I'll give you a recursive function example that is close.

Here is an example of how you might use recursion to sum all the numbers from 1 to 100 (it's close to what you're trying to do).

```
int sumAllNumbers(int actualNumber, int limit)
{
   if (actualNumber < limit) return sumAllNumbers(actualNumber + 1, limit) + actualNumber;
   return actualNumber;
}
```

if you get how this works, I think you can figure out how to make a recursive function to reverse a string.
The main thing you have to remember is that you must have a condition that will stop the recursion.